# How to grep on a ncurses display (refreshed every second)?

Tags: command-line, terminal, top, ncurses

When running the useful tool `tcptrack` in the terminal (over SSH), it displays this:

```
Client                Server            State        Idle A Speed
1.2.3.4:44054         5.5.5.5:443       ESTABLISHED  0s     2 MB/s
2.2.2.2:52930         5.5.5.5:443       CLOSING      1s     1 MB/s
3.3.3.3:80            5.5.5.5:443       ESTABLISHED  27s    0 B/s
4.4.4.4:3074          5.5.5.5:443       ESTABLISHED  4m     0 B/s
6.6.6.6:3074          5.5.5.5:443       ESTABLISHED  16m    0 B/s
...
```

with an automatic refresh once per second (or so). Note that the following question would be equally valid for `top` or similar tools.

How to filter out every row for which the column `Idle` is bigger than `10s` (also `1m` for minutes)?

More generally, **how to do some sort of `grep` or `awk` but on a display which uses `ncurses` or similar, rather than on a classical file?**

Obviously, `tcptrack -i eth0 | grep ...` does not work.

Note: [`tcptrack`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcptrack) has no such option, and editing its source code would be quite long.

Comment: For `top`, there is batch mode with `-b`.

Comment: Good to know @pLumo! Does this mean the full list is rewritten to stdout every second, even if nothing has changed? (BTW, it seems there is no similar way with `tcptrack`).

Comment: There's no way to do that in general. And you don't have to edit the entire source code of `tcptrack`, only the relevant parts.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561927/how-to-save-output-of-tcptrack-into-a-text-file